# Removes some key/values pairs from an object

Tags: javascript

suppose i have an object like this:

```
object = {date: '', time: '', bar: ''}
```

How to remove the date and time keys with their values. I dont want to use delete. Is there a possibililty to use filter function?

Comment: _"I dont want to use delete"_ Why not? `delete object['date']; delete object['time'];` is the obvious answer.

Comment: Filtering is not removing.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without using delete?

Comment: You could use `omit` (Lodash/Underscore/other?) or write your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Object.keys to get all of the keys of your object and then filter and reduce to rebuild a new object:

```
object = Object.keys(object).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== 'date' && key !== 'time';
}).reduce(function(acc, key) {
     acc[key] = object[key];
     return acc;
}, {});
```

It would probably easier to simply use delete though

Comment: Great answer, another enhancement...if a key contains a specific value. For example if {status: all} how will i remove this keys which contains the value all?

Comment: You have access to the object array the whole time, so you can do whatever you want. I use it in the reduce but you can use it in the filter as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use es6 features, and you don't mind to create a new object, you can use destructuring + rest operator:

```
const yourObject = {date: '', time: '', bar: ''};
const {date, time, ...other} = yourObject;
console.log(other);
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in all browsers. Otherwise a pretty good solution.

Comment: that is not removing, but creating a new object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash.

```
var object = {date: '', time: '', bar: ''};
_.omit(object, ['date','time']);
```

Pass in the keys in the array inside the lodash function

Answer (score 1):

> *"How to remove the date and time keys with their values. I dont want to use `delete`."*

Sure, you can use `Reflect.deleteProperty` if you don't like the `delete` operator for some reason.

```js
var object = {date: '', time: '', bar: ''};

["date","time"].forEach(k => Reflect.deleteProperty(object, k));
      
console.log(object);
```

This actually removes the properties from the object instead of creating a new object and overwriting the variable reference, which isn't the same operation, and may have undesired side effects depending on how this is used.